# How to structure JSON file with multiple objects

Tags: json

To this date, I have put one object into a JSON file for use in my JavaScript code. Like this:

```
"disc":[
{"key":"0001","film":{"title":"12 Monkeys","director":"Terry Gilliam",...}},
...
}
]
```

Now I want to include five objects in the same file. How should I construct the file?

Comment: I don't think I understood your question clearly, the five objects you have are they in  same structure and type, or they are totally different, 
You can just add each object as an item of your json matrix,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[{"disc":[ {"key":"0001","film":{"title":"12 Monkeys","director":"Terry Gilliam"}} ]},{"disc":[ {"key":"0001","film":{"title":"12 Monkeys","director":"Terry Gilliam"}} ]},{"disc":[ {"key":"0001","film":{"title":"12 Monkeys","director":"Terry Gilliam"}} ]},{"disc":[ {"key":"0001","film":{"title":"12 Monkeys","director":"Terry Gilliam"}} ]},{"disc":[ {"key":"0001","film":{"title":"12 Monkeys","director":"Terry Gilliam"}} ]}]
```

Comment: Thank you. This passes jsLint.